# User session ending when clicking on a link

Tags: sessions

I have a site with a login form on the front end for the user to log into the site.  The login works ok, but when they click on any link to another page, their session ends and they get logged out.  This is an issue as I have {if logged_in} tags in various parts of the site.

I'm using EE 2.2.2 and I have set the Session type Session ID only.  Setting any other session type dosn't allow them to log in at all.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old bug that caused a lot people problems. You can read the lengthy bug report here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/17423

Bottom line: you'll need to update to the latest version of EE

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for that.  That sounds about right.  I was hoping upgrading wouldn't be the solution, it's not really an option with this site.  Just out of curiosity, I'm also having an issue where I can only sign in with certain usernames, other usernames give an error: "You must submit your username and password".  Would this be related to the same bug?